# Как на Android сделать панельку, выдвигаемую из view, а не из края экрана (по типу spinner)?

Tags: android, android-spinner, bottom-sheet

Для минимального решения задачи, в принципе хватает и spinner'а - выбрать пункт, и изменить содержание активити в соответствии с выбранным пунктом. Но далее на выпадающем списке необходимо будет где-то разместить пару кнопок (не на каждой строке spinner, а общих для всех строк), что нереализуемо.

Поэтому нужна выдвижная панелька, которая выдвигается например из TextView (ну или рядом с TextView, но не перекрывая ее, а наоборот - создавая эффект spinner'а).

Как сделать такую панель?

Смотрел сдандартные "выдвигалки-слайдеры", смотрел разные библиотеки - у всех панелька выдвигается из края экрана.

Comment: PopupMenu, PopupWindow

Comment: Вроде можно с помощью `registerForContextMenu(view)`

Comment: _"что нереализуемо"_ Можно создать класс унаследовав Spinner, и использовать свою разметку.